# Can't connect Tomcat 6 and oracle 10g XE for jsp database connectivity

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jsp

I am using Eclispe ganymede,tomcat6 and oracle 10g XE. I have connected all of them.Everything is working fine.

But I have created a jsp file which creates a table in database that is not working. There is no error. But when I check into database there is no table created.

My coding :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%
    Connection con=null;
      try
    {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","123");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table Black ( "
                  + "   id INT PRIMARY KEY, firstName VARCHAR(20), lastName VARCHAR(20), "
                  + "   title VARCHAR(20), salary INT " + ")");
        out.println("Table Created");

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(NamingException e)
    {
    out.println(e.getMessage());    
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            if(con!=null)
                con.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
        }
    }
    %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is what error says:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.data_jsp._jspService(data_jsp.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.data_jsp._jspService(data_jsp.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.data_jsp._jspService(data_jsp.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Now anyone tell me how to connect this program to database.

Comment: How did it go after you included the oracle drivers? You can either put the oracle driver jar in the build path of your project, or under some lib/ in tomcat.

Comment: i have put oracle driver in my build path and this error raised.

Comment: Well the error is due to the build/run-configuration, not in your code. The ClassNotFoundException means there is a missing .jar somewhere. It should be found if it is under a lib directory of the tomcat server in wich you run it. It can be in yuor build-path but is not in your .war or .ear or however you deploy it.

Comment: I dont know its name, the one which contains the oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver class. Judging by the name it is the oracle jdbc driver which you can download from oracles websites. Tomcat doesnt come pre-installed with that driver, so you need to add it.

Comment: So,have you added the ojdbcX.jar into the lib directory of your tomcat? Then what happened?

Comment: yup its already done........still same error............

Answer (score 2):

What is the output, is there a stacktrace? Have you defined the datasource as testdb?

You shouldnt anyway be doing sql-statements from a JSP page, put the sql-statements behind a DAO or use Hibernate or similar ORM tool.

Here is the http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html download page for Oracles JDBC drivers. Take the matching one for your database, and the matching version of your Java vm. And put it under your tomcats lib/ directory.

Comment: check again there is stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Any exceptions raised ?. Don't use JDBC connection code in Jsp .Instead keep in a DAO class.

Or Jsp tab libraries can be used.

[SQL Tag Library](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html)

Check this link to solve the issue .

[Oracle.jdbc. driver.OracleDriver problem](http://www.coderanch.com/t/303703/JDBC/java/Oracle-jdbc-driver-OracleDriver)

Comment: According to the Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver Oracle driver is not in classpath.

Comment: Include classes12.jar in classpath

Comment: Try adding ojdbc14.jar in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the ojdbc14.jar file in your Deployment Assembly in your project.
Using eclipse :

**proj --> properties --> Deployment Assembly --> Add --> Add your jar file.**

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that in my project I had to change from:

```
String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
```

to

```
String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
```

I am using Oracle Database 11g Release 2.